# Multipatch to collada says Background processing has encountered a serious error and is unable to continue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcglobe, serious-application-error, collada

I was trying to convert a 2D shapefile of building footprint to 3D SketchUp-readable file.

I first opened the shapefile in ArcGlobe, and in properties set building height as extrusion parameter. Then I used "3D to feature" to convert shapefiles to multipatch.

The last step was supposed to be "Multipatch to collada", one conversion tool, but ArcGIS crashed, saying:

> Background processing has encountered a serious error and is unable to continue

I tried disabling background processing, and then the application crashed when re-running the tool.

Any thoughts what happened, or any suggestions how to convert shapefile (with height value) to collada?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 student edition, on Windows operation system.

Answer (score 2):

I was told that this type of crash (Im getting it to) may have to do with the way that the program is accessing your graphics card.

I have staff that are working to resolve the issue for me but it is something to investigate.

I believe it is briefly mentioned in the Interpolate Polygons to Multipatch documentation for v.10.